# Auto create tables with JPA2 and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lombok

I have trouble with auto creating tables in the database.

My **gradle dependecies**:

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version: '1.0.0.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '4.3.6.Final'
compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.0.0'
```

My **entity class** (two other classes look similar):

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class StreetData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ParkingSpaceData> parkingSpaces;
}
```

My **persistance.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">
<persistence-unit name="parking-database-unit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>soa.parking.database.domain.StreetData</class>
    <class>soa.parking.database.domain.ParkingSpaceData</class>
    <class>soa.parking.database.domain.TicketData</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/parking" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*********" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

These all I pack into .war file and deploy on jBoss server. In the logs I see SQL generated by Hibernate (listing below) but no tables are created in the database. There aren't any errors during deploy.

```
10:40:22,210 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 737) HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
10:40:22,212 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 737) Hibernate: alter table StreetData_ParkingSpaceData drop constraint FKdbu6ec2cjp0lytdht5ct34r2
10:40:22,212 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 737) Hibernate: alter table StreetData_ParkingSpaceData drop constraint FKnp5q60wl9xmiwpc8o1in8m7si
10:40:22,212 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 737) Hibernate: drop table if exists ParkingSpaceData cascade
10:40:22,214 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 737) Hibernate: drop table if exists StreetData cascade
10:40:22,215 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 737) Hibernate: drop table if exists StreetData_ParkingSpaceData cascade
10:40:22,215 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 737) Hibernate: drop table if exists TicketData cascade
10:40:22,215 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 737) Hibernate: create table ParkingSpaceData (id  bigserial not null, empty boolean, primary key (id))
10:40:22,216 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 737) Hibernate: create table StreetData (id  bigserial not null, name varchar(255), primary key (id))
10:40:22,217 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 737) Hibernate: create table StreetData_ParkingSpaceData (StreetData_id int8 not null, parkingSpaces_id int8 not null, primary key (StreetData_id, parkingSpaces_id))
10:40:22,217 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 737) Hibernate: create table TicketData (id  bigserial not null, createdDate timestamp, invalidateDate timestamp, streetId int8, primary key (id))
10:40:22,218 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 737) Hibernate: alter table StreetData_ParkingSpaceData add constraint UK_fpad6yr01tqc30pvgc4decjq7 unique (parkingSpaces_id)
10:40:22,218 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 737) Hibernate: alter table StreetData_ParkingSpaceData add constraint FKdbu6ec2cjp0lytdht5ct34r2 foreign key (parkingSpaces_id) references ParkingSpaceData
10:40:22,220 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 737) Hibernate: alter table StreetData_ParkingSpaceData add constraint FKnp5q60wl9xmiwpc8o1in8m7si foreign key (StreetData_id) references StreetData
10:40:22,222 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 737) HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

What I should change to get tables in the databse?

**[EDIT]**

Tables are created only on 'fresh' database i.e. created before deploy. And I can insert some data (listing below). But tables are not updated after next artifact deploy. I see the same logs with drops and creates operations. Same logs are appear event if database isn't exist.

```
StreetData street = new StreetData();
street.setName("A");

EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("parking-database-unit");
EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(street);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

**[EDIT 2]**
Is it possible that entities are created in hibernate cache on start up and not committed to the database? I create DAO service to manage database in another module (connected using EJB).

Comment: As far as I can read in your logs, tables are well created.

Comment: @russellhoff It looks strange for me too as in the database no relations found.

Comment: Have you tried inserting data using JPA? Maybe you're looking in the wrong place when introspecting the database

Comment: @crizzis I have updated my question with insert data code

Comment: "But tables are not updated after next artifact deploy"

<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" /> have you tried update? create drops tables every time you deploy stuff.

Comment: Try `@Table` and check

Comment: I change property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `create-drop`. It seems work but only after executing (or creating) `EntityManager` to insert some data.

Comment: @soorapadman I have already tried `@Table`. It isn't change anything. Table annotation should be used only for change column names.